# Upgrade from Windows Vista to Windows 8. Then downgrade from Windows 8 to Windows 7

Tags: windows, upgrade, downgrade

Is it possible to upgrade from Windows Vista to Windows 8 and then downgrade from Windows 8 to Windows 7?

Comment: It is possible, but with some limitations. See http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9230815/Microsoft_will_allow_downgrades_from_Windows_8_to_Windows_7_Vista

Comment: Sure is, make system images of each after they are installed, restore the one you want at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only if you have the necessary Windows 7 licence.

(*Retail* Windows 8 upgrades do not include downgrade rights or media.)